# Кастомная форма сектора/div

Tags: html, css, css3

На сайте https://www.pomwonderful.com/ используется необычная реализация div секторов. Они в форме трапеции (на бок). Как можно добиться такого же эффекта? Пример картинки снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам background:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот сайт нагружает мой процессор сильнее чем Doom 2016. Может, лучше не надо добиваться такого же?)

Comment: @andreymal ахахаххаха) Вот тебе сайт будущего под RTTTTX 200800 с Intel i79-10000.

А если честно, то картинки достаточно, чтобы понять суть проблемы.

Comment: А по теме вопроса — там не дивы, там тупо рисуется картинка по canvas'у

Comment: @andreymal Можешь привести пример кода?

Comment: Вы сами дали ссылку на пример, открывайте да смотрите код)

Comment: @andreymal clip-path может использовать? https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Вполне возможно, он может вам подойти, если решает все стоящие перед вами задачи. Тем не менее конкретно на сайте pomwonderful.com не clip-path и не дивы

Comment: @andreymal помог тот сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать через CSS clip-path
https://kilianvalkhof.com/2017/design/sloped-edges-with-consistent-angle-in-css/